# Iterating and rendering an ActiveRecord_Relation for Views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view, controller

I'm struggling to 'crack open' an ActiveRecord_Relation for rendering in Views in Rails. I get a response such as:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Request id: 25803, time_inserted: "2019-07-27 17:20:17", time_modified: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", time_completed: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", disposition: "Forced Ignore", account: "301385", trans_uuid: "008326d4-b090-11e9-aead-0282b642e944", customers_identifier: "46134865dfdsaasdfs4", customers_reason: "E", customers_customer: "reveltransit", request_state: "NY", request_license: "12345678", request_lastname: "BOLLS", request_firstname: "JEFF", request_middlename: nil, request_dob: nil, request_gender: "">, #<Request id: 25919, time_inserted: "2019-07-27 17:40:17", time_modified: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", time_completed: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", disposition: "Forced Ignore", account: "301385", trans_uuid: "008326d4-b090-11e9-aead-0282b642e944", customers_identifier: "4434kjk34k3j43kk34j3", customers_reason: "E", customers_customer: "reveltransit", request_state: "NY", request_license: "12345678", request_lastname: "BOLLS", request_firstname: "JEFF", request_middlename: nil, request_dob: nil, request_gender: "">, #<Request id: 26069, time_inserted: "2019-07-27 18:00:20", time_modified: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", time_completed: "2019-08-03 17:37:48", disposition: "Forced Ignore", account: "301385", trans_uuid: "008326d4-b090-11e9-aead-0282b642e944", customers_identifier: "461348652f19ffc4901efc8e31c4", customers_reason: "E", customers_customer: "reveltransit", request_state: "NY", request_license: "12345678", request_lastname: "BOLLS", request_firstname: "JEFF", request_middlename: nil, request_dob: nil, request_gender: "">]>
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord

    establish_connection(:development) 
    self.table_name = "incoming"

    def self.search(search) 
     self.where(:trans_uuid => search)
    end 



end
```

The Search method in my Controller:

```
 def search
    results = Request.search(params[:search])
    @records = results.pluck(:trans_uuid) 
    byebug 
end
```

and Views:

```
<%= form_with url: requests_search_path, method: :get do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :search %>
<%= form.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>



<h3><u>Search Results</u></h3><br />

<h4><%= @records.map { |record| record } %></h4>
```

Cannot get it to render in view because it's always an array. If I try to iterate over it, I get a `no method` error.

Comment: Which variable is always an array? Which line gives you an error? Could you paste the full stacktrace or at least the full error message?

Comment: `results` is the returned `ActiveReocrd_Relation` object. `@records` is an array and then I try to iterate over that using `each` as suggested by Sebastian Palma but nothing renders in views but nothing renders.

Comment: _If I try to iterate over it, I get a no method error_, can you add that error?

Comment: I apologize. I think I fixed that issue. That was before I used the `.pluck` method in the controller before it gets iterated over in `views`. Now there are no errors and the return is https://gist.github.com/dsound-zz/e548efdb15d4afc784f03cfebdd351ad

Comment: The action is returning a JS response, see the logs (_RequestsController#search as JS_). There should be a JS file which can work with that result.

Comment: Woah missed that. Hmm. I'll have to look into that to see how to work with it. Never experienced this before. Is this something having to do with Rails 6 and Webpacker?

Comment: It depends. We can't see more than what you added to your question, but there should be something specific that's making that action return a JS response.

Comment: The `class Request` uses the `establish_connection` method to connect directly to the AWS MySQL database. Other than that, I'm not sure how it would process the returned object as JS.

Comment: What about your routes?

Comment: Routes are the usual: `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'requests/index', to: 'requests#index'
  get 'requests/show', to: 'requests#show'
  get 'requests/search', to: 'requests#search'
  
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end`

Comment: `pluck` returns an array. You're using `map` on that, which also returns an array. Maybe you can try: `<% @records.each do |record| <%= record %> end %>`

Comment: I figured out the problem. I'm using `form_with` in `views`. You have to opt-out of JS processing by using `:local`. Wow...that was a whole day of fun!

Answer (score 0):

So on further research and having never used `form_with` before, I realized that by default, `form_with` assumes you'll be using AJAX. To opt out, you must include `:local` in the `form_with` method in your `views`.

So `<%= form_with model: @request, method: :get do |form| %>` needs to be `<%= form_with model: @request, local: true, method: :get do |form| %>`

from the docs:

*3.1.1 form_with
form_with is a helper that assists with writing forms. By default, form_with assumes that your form will be using Ajax. You can opt out of this behavior by passing the :local option form_with.*